# How to configure the default XmlSerializer used in .net core api

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

Does anybody know how to configure the XML serializer which is added when you use the IMVCBuilder in the **Startup** up class of a .net core api project. Specifically when you use this:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat; // UTC (ISO 8601) format for dates
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    })
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
```

I tried using the `AddXmlOptions` extension method but there are no properties the `MvcXmlOptions` Class (apart from `AllowRfc7807CompliantProblemDetailsFormat`)

The specific setting I am trying to configure is to omit the xml declaration from the root element. There a plenty of answers on here which address this but they all involve instantiating a new XmlSerializer. I need the setting to apply the default serializer used by a controller when the Accept header is set to `application/xml`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get to the [`XmlWriterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.xmlserializeroutputformatter.writersettings) used by the output-formatter using something like the following:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    var xmlWriterSettings = options.OutputFormatters
        .OfType<XmlSerializerOutputFormatter>()
        .Single()
        .WriterSettings;

    xmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
});
```

The call to `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` adds an instance of `XmlSerializerOutputFormatter`. The code above finds that particular instance and modifies its settings accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
services.Configure<MvcXmlOptions>(options =>
{
    //set options here
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately has the same issue as the AddXmlOptions extension methods, in that there are no properties on the MvcXmlOptions class.